# Get number of days between 2 dates in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'd like to order rows by an integer + number of days passed since today.

However this:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

db.Items.OrderBy(x => x.SomeInteger + (x.Date - now).Days);
```

Gives the following warning:

`The LINQ expression 'orderby' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.`

In .NET framework it was possible to do this: `DbFunctions.DiffDays`

What's the equivalent in ASP.NET core?

Comment: Okay, looks painful but there is this on EF github https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9549

Comment: Normally, order by clause is column name(s). Could you show us how you write this in SQL query before writing in EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've opened this issue on github and it looks like it's now fixed and will be available in 2.1.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10468

Workaround:

```
public static class DbUtility
{
    public static int DateDiff(string diffType, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(DateDiff)} should be performed on database");
    }
}
```

In `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.HasDbFunction(typeof(DbUtility)
        .GetMethod(nameof(DbUtility.DateDiff)))
        .HasTranslation(args => {
            var newArgs = args.ToArray();
            newArgs[0] = new SqlFragmentExpression((string)((ConstantExpression)newArgs[0]).Value);
            return new SqlFunctionExpression(
                "DATEDIFF",
                typeof(int),
                newArgs);
        });
}
```

Used like this:

```
DbUtility.DateDiff("day", x.DateAdded, now)
```

Answer (score 11):

From [pull request](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/10264) use

```
var lstPeople = cxt
.People.Where(p => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(p.Birth, DateTime.Now) > 0 )
.ToList();
```